# Generate one hot encodings from dict values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I was trying to make a one hot array based on my dictionary characters: First, I created a numpy zeros that has row X column (3x7) and then I search for the id of each character and assign "1" to each row of the numpy array.

My goal is to assign each character with one hot array. "1" as "present" and "0" as "not present". Here we have 3 characters so we should have 3 rows, while the 7 columns serve as the characters existence in the dictionary.

However, I received an error stating that "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index". Can anyone please help me in this? Thank you

In order not to make everyone misunderstand my dictionary:

Here is how I create the dic:

```
sent = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
aaa = len(sent)
aa = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(sent)}
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
sentences = ["b", "c", "e"]
a = {}
for xx in sentences:
   a[xx] = aa[xx]
a = {"b":1, "c":2, "e":4}
aa =len(a)

for x,y in a.items():
    aa = np.zeros((aa,aaa))
    aa[y] = 1

print(aa)
```

Current Error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

My expected output:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

-------> Since its dictionary so the index arrangement should be different and the "1"s within the array is a dummy so that I can show my expected output.

Comment: What if it was `a = {"a":0, "b":1, "c":5}`?

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding but since I created the dictionary based on 
sent = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
aa = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(sent)}................ it wont become something like above you mentioned. Since you have 3 characters then it will be {"a":0, "b":1, "c":2} based on my codes.

Comment: Okay, then what will `[a, b, a, d, c]` give me?

Comment: I assume your [a,b,a,d,c] is a list of characters, too? Then it will become like this, right?b = ["a", "b", "a", "d", "c"] for x in b: print(a[x])................. output [0,1,0,3,2]?? But I dont get why we need to find these? Can please let me know since I am still beginner

Comment: Just trying to understand the reasoning behind how the one hot matrix is generated. Is it based on lexicographical order? Or does it have to do with the order in which it appears... etc.

Comment: Nope, the order is depending on the numerical value it assigned with. For example, c is assigned with 2. Since 1-hot is based on the existence of each character based on the dimension of the dictionary of the sentences. That is why I generate a np.zeros that have the same length with the number of characters and then assign "1" to the numpy array for each row = each character and the other columns all "0"s. Simply said, it will be a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

c = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0].... This is just example and my codes above also an example for me to understand it and to show my intention

Comment: What if you just do `np.eye(5)`?

Comment: I am sorry but I think you misunderstood how my intention to build a one-hot array for Neural network. np.eye(5) will give me a diagonal instead of giving me the value based on the assign integers. For example, if my characters is like you said above {"a":0, "b":1, "c":2} then it would be able to use np.eye(5). I guess, I did not specify it clearly, my mistakes, my dictionary might contains many characters with many assigned num values. These 5 characters might have different values and even further from each other and not like the dummy values above. Example 100 characters in the dictionary

Comment: Unfortunately, dictionaries only support unique keys, so that's not something you can do. You should find a different representation or make your problem more clear.

Comment: Let me change a little to my codes. Hold on.

Comment: true. dictionary only unique keys But my intention is to get the values into the numpy array. I am still trying it. XD

Comment: I made some changes and please see whether is it understandable if not I will alter again.

Comment: Can you update your expected output to reflect the change in input please?

Comment: Done, I updated my "aaa = len(sent)"...."aa = np.zeros((aa,aaa))" and the expected output. Please check and thank you again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Setting indices

(Comments inlined.)

```
# Sort and extract the indices.
idx = sorted(a.values())
# Initialise a matrix of zeros.
aa = np.zeros((len(idx), max(idx) + 1))
# Assign 1 to appropriate indices.
aa[np.arange(len(aa)), idx] = 1
```

```
print (aa)
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

---

#### `numpy.eye`

```
idx = sorted(a.values())
eye = np.eye(max(idx) + 1)    
aa = eye[idx]
```

```
print (aa)
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you and I just done another solution. Just share it here for future readers. import numpy as np
a = {"a":0, "b":1, "c":2, "d":3, "e":4}
aa =len(a)
i = 0
yy = []
for x,y in a.items():
    yy.append(y)
yy = np.asarray(yy)
b = np.zeros((aa,aa))
b[np.arange(aa),yy] = 1
    
print(b)

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll bet you could use a [`dok_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html) to great effect here.

Comment: @JJson please post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Scott Thanks. I just answered the question based on the wording and example. I spent a long time trying to get OP to clarify what it was they wanted, as you can read from the comments under the question. If you have a better idea for the title, I invite you to edit the question so we can all benefit.

Comment: @Scott. Please edit my questions if possible. I am still having trouble in trying to explain it in a understandable way. Thank you and I will post it as answer too.

Comment: I have one question, do we really have to extract the indices no matter what and store it in numpy array? If there is another way round to learn it would be good too.

Comment: @JJson I'm sure there are other ways of doing it... This is just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

A one hot encoding treats a sample as a sequence, where each element of the sequence is the index into a vocabulary indicating whether that element (like a word or letter) is in the sample. For example if your vocabulary was the lower-case alphabet, a one-hot encoding of the work cat might look like:

```
 [1, 0., 1, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 1, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

Indicating that this word contains the letters `c`, `a`, and `t`.

To make a one-hot encoding you need two things a vocabulary lookup with all the possible values (when using words this is why the matrices can get so large because the vocabulary is huge!). But if encoding the lower-case alphabet you only need 26.

Then you typically represent your samples as indexes in the vocabulary. So the set of words might look like this:

```
#bag, cab, fad
sentences = np.array([[1, 0, 6], [2, 0, 1], [5, 0, 3]])
```

When you one-hot encode that you will get a matrix 3 x 26:

```
vocab = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

#bag, cab, fad
sentences = np.array([[1, 0, 6], [2, 0, 1], [5, 0, 3]])

def onHot(sequences, dimension=len(vocab)):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
      results[i, sequence] = 1
    return results

onHot(sentences)
```

Which results in thee one-hot encoded samples with a 26 letter vocabulary ready to be fed to a neural network:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Youre right! I have posted my answer and also I forgot that I have to change my indices to numpy array in order for it to load into the numpy array as well. thank you so much for point out the problem and please check my answer and let me know whether my understanding this time is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

My solution and for future readers:

I build the dictionary for the "sent" list:

```
sent = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
aaa = len(sent)
aa = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(sent)}
```

Then I find the indices for my own sentences based on the dictionary and assigned the numerical values to these sentences.

```
import numpy as np
sentences = ["b", "c", "e"]
a = {}
for xx in sentences:
   a[xx] = aa[xx]
a = {"b":1, "c":2, "e":4}
aa =len(a)
```

I extract the indices from the new assignment of "a":

```
index = []
for x,y in a.items():
    index.append(y)
```

Then I create another numpy array for these extract indices from the a.

```
index = np.asarray(index)
```

Now I create numpy zeros to store the existence of each character:

```
new = np.zeros((aa,aaa))
new[np.arange(aa), index] = 1
```

print(new)

Output:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one by using sklearn.preprocessing

The lines are quite long and not much difference. I don:t know why but produced a similar results.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
sent = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
aaa = len(sent)
aa = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(sent)}


sentences = ["b", "c", "e"]
a = {}
for xx in sentences:
   a[xx] = aa[xx]
a = {"a":0, "b":1, "c":2, "d":3, "e":4, "f":5, "g":6}
aa =len(a)

index = []
for x,y in a.items():
    index.append([y])

index = np.asarray(index)

enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(index)

print(enc.transform([[1], [2], [4]]).toarray())
```

Output

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) with a [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from `sklearn`.

```
import sklearn.preprocessing
import numpy as np

texty_data = np.array(["a", "c", "b"])
le = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(texty_data)
integery_data = le.transform(texty_data)
ohe = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder().fit(integery_data.reshape((-1,1)))
onehot_data = ohe.transform(integery_data.reshape((-1,1)))
```

Stores it sparse, so that's handy.  You can also use a [`LabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) to streamline this:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing
import numpy as np

texty_data = np.array(["a", "c", "b"])
lb = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer().fit(texty_data)
onehot_data = lb.transform(texty_data)
print(onehot_data, lb.inverse_transform(onehot_data))
```

Comment: Ok thanks and I received this error: "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0. 2. 1.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: I tried to implement using sklearn by your recommendation. I repost another one more solution. Please check and give me suggestion on how to include the transform with string instead. thank you